# Returning a result ONLY for unique criteria, with multiple criteria. OFFSET(), FREQUENCY(), SUMIF()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, unique, offset

Here is an overview of what I am trying to do.

i have 6 columns
A is alphanumerical
B is text
C,D are binary data
E is text
F is the column I want to populate with binary data

To simplify I would like to test columns B,C,D,E against a set of criteria (each column has its own set of criteria to test against).  If all B,C,D, and E are "true" I want to return a "1" in column F.

Now here comes the problem I'm having.

Basically A is an ID#, and B,C,D,E are criteria each must met to return a "1" in column F. The problem is that there are multiple rows of each ID#.  It doesn't matter which ID# instance, but I only want to return ONE "1" in column F for each unique ID#.

Once a 1 is returned for a particular ID#, I don't need it to actually check the remainder of the same ID# rows, it can move on to the next ID# if need be.

I'm returning a "1" for the simplicity of the question, but eventually I want to have multiple criteria sets, and return a letter corresponding to each set instead of a "1".

Ex/

Row 1   A="1D45", B=true, C=false, D=true, E=true -- Returns F="0"

Row 2   A="1D45", B=true, C=false, D=true, E=false -- Returns F="0"

Row 3   A="1D45", B=true, C=true, D=true, E=true -- Returns F="1"

Row 4   A="1D45", B=true, C=true, D=true, E=true -- Returns F="1", BUT i want it to show 0

Row 5   A="1D45", B=true, C=false, D=true, E=false -- Returns F="0"

Row 6   A="1D45", B=true, C=true, D=true, E=true -- Returns F="1", BUT i want it to show 0

Row 7   A="1D46", B=true, C=true, D=true, E=true -- Returns F="1"

etc. etc.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulas are:

```
F1:
=--AND(B1,C1,D1,E1)

F2:
=AND(B2,C2,D2,E2)*(0=COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,F$1:F1,1))
```

Fill down column `F` from `F2`.

In the first `AND`, you can replace `B2` and `C2` etc with your actual conditions. The last condition is actually what checks that this ID in column A has not yet got a value of `1` in column `F` above it.

[image]

Comment: Works! Thanks so much.

Comment: Just out of curosity: I do get that the first cell has to be different to avoid a circular link.  But how come it doesn't work if i change the ranges in the countif to cover the entire data range instead of just from current cell to first cell.  Thanks again.

Comment: @IntaStellar you're welcome. You said it; if you cover the whole range the calculating cell will be inside and we get circular reference. Also, keep in mind that `COUNTIFS` has strict rules, especially, the range parameters must be of the same size, so you can't change one of them without the others.

Comment: If my range of data is Rows 1-8.  F1 will be its own formula.  But I don't get why theoretically the COUNTIF doesn't work if it is (0=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$8,A2,F$1:F$8,1)) with only the "A2" changing when you drag the formula.  

Thanks so very much for your help.  I've already gotten my assignment done, but I'm just curious for educational purposes.

Comment: @IntaStellar our formulas are entered in F2 to F8, right? So consider this formula entered in `F3` for example: the range `F$1:F$8` will include it, so the cell will be referring to itself in the calculation, hence the circular reference. Besides please next time when it is an assignment it would be nice to say it in the opening question.

Comment: Got It! I just leveled up. Thanks SO MUCH!